# VBA that copy and paste if conditions are met

Tags: excel, vba

I wrote some code that reads a report generated automatically (with info always at the same place), checks if condition at a column is met and then copy the values wanted to a new workbook.

```
    Sub Truckstaytry()

' Organize it before mess around
    Workbooks("TruckStay.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
    Workbooks("TruckStay.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells.Address).UnMerge

    Dim iCntr
    Dim rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Range(Cells.Address)

    For iCntr = rng.Column + rng.Columns.Count - 1 To rng.Column Step -1
        If Application.WorksheetFunction.CountA(Columns(iCntr)) = 0 Then Columns(iCntr).EntireColumn.Delete
    Next
  
' select by cond.
a = Workbooks("TruckStay.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 21 To a
    
    If Workbooks("TruckStay.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 23).Value <> "" Then
    If Workbooks("TruckStay.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 23).Value <> "0  Dia(s) " Then
Workbooks("TruckStay.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i).Copy
```

The code works great, but I can't figure out how to copy the other rows and organize them right below their original rows of source, or define the copy by a range that repeats through the process. Below is where I am stuck:

```
'    ElseIf Workbooks("TruckStay.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 23).Value = "1  Dia(s) " Then
'Workbooks("TruckStay.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i + 2).Copy
'    ElseIf Workbooks("TruckStay.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(i, 23).Value = "1  Dia(s) " Then
'Workbooks("TruckStay.xls").Worksheets("Sheet1").Rows(i + 3).Copy

' Paste
Workbooks("TruckStayReport.xlsx").Worksheets("Data Report").Activate
b = Workbooks("TruckStayReport.xlsx").Worksheets("Data Report").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
Workbooks("TruckStayReport.xlsx").Worksheets("Data Report").Cells(b + 1, 1).Select

ActiveSheet.Paste
   

End If
End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I'd be tempted to use a filter and copy the lot in one hit.

Comment: @kevin9999 filters don't work because the report comes very disorganized and with merged cells, i could unmerge it all, but anyway.. i prefer the code doing everything to avoid human error